# net-snmp api use user's credentials

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp

I have a program that makes SNMP calls to other machines. However, my current implementation for establishing the session has the credentials hard-coded, such as:

```
const char *our_v3_passphrase = "The Net-SNMP Demo Password";

 /*
 * Initialize the SNMP library
 */
init_snmp("snmpdemoapp");

/*
 * Initialize a "session" that defines who we're going to talk to
 */
snmp_sess_init( &session );                   /* set up defaults */
session.peername = strdup("test.net-snmp.org");

/* set the SNMPv3 user name */
session.securityName = strdup("SHAUser");
session.securityNameLen = strlen(session.securityName);

/* set the security level to authenticated, but not encrypted */
session.securityLevel = SNMP_SEC_LEVEL_AUTHNOPRIV;

/* set the authentication method to SHA */
session.securityAuthProto = usmHMACSHA1AuthProtocol;
session.securityAuthProtoLen = sizeof(usmHMACSHA1AuthProtocol)/sizeof(oid);
session.securityAuthKeyLen = USM_AUTH_KU_LEN;

/* set the authentication key to a SHA hashed version of our
   passphrase "The Net-SNMP Demo Password" (which must be at least 8
   characters long) */
if (generate_Ku(session.securityAuthProto,
                session.securityAuthProtoLen,
                (u_char *) our_v3_passphrase, strlen(our_v3_passphrase),
                session.securityAuthKey,
                &session.securityAuthKeyLen) != SNMPERR_SUCCESS) {
    snmp_perror(argv[0]);
    snmp_log(LOG_ERR,
             "Error generating Ku from authentication pass phrase. \n");
    exit(1);
}

/*
 * Open the session
 */
ss = snmp_open(&session);          

if (!ss) {
  snmp_sess_perror("ack", &session);
  SOCK_CLEANUP;
  exit(1);
}
```

I would like to derive the SNMP credentials from the machine instead of hard-coding them, using net-snmp's paths for resolving where configuration files are stored.

I have a configuration file in ~/.snmp/snmp.conf that contains entries such as:

```
defVersion 3
defSecurityName SHAUser
defAuthPassphrase "The Net-SNMP Demo Password"
defAuthType SHA
defSecurityLevel authNoPriv
```

I can get this to work when I run the program by itself (removing the hard-coded credentials and just not setting securityName or generating the KU):

```
 /*
 * Initialize the SNMP library
 */
init_snmp("snmpdemoapp");

/*
 * Initialize a "session" that defines who we're going to talk to
 */
snmp_sess_init( &session );                   /* set up defaults */
session.peername = strdup("test.net-snmp.org");
/*
 * Open the session
 */
ss = snmp_open(&session);          

if (!ss) {
  snmp_sess_perror("ack", &session);
  SOCK_CLEANUP;
  exit(1);
}
```

but if I use this as part of a daemon, the credentials aren't being found. I verified the credentials weren't being derived by listening to tcp port 161 and observing the outgoing SNMP traffic being sent without the securityName being set (just blank).

The service manager I'm using is systemd.

My question is: How do I configure the net-snmp API such that it takes the credentials of the user running the program, when the program is ran as a daemon process?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was traced back to the daemon's service file not exporting the home directory needed for the daemon to parse the configuration file.

So, in the service file, I added:

```
[Service]
...
Environment=HOME=/root
...
```

Stopped the daemons, did a daemon-reload, and restarted my daemon process (and dependent processes). Behavior was as expected.